# making the whole page blur when I click on a certain button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a button and want the whole body to go blurry when I click on it and show an alert or a pop-up message. this is what I have been trying to do:

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('body').css("filter","blur(2px)");
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<div class="phone_num d-none d-xl-block">
  <a class="boxed-btn3" href="{% url 'homepage' %}" onclick="myFunction">{% trans 'try' %}</a>
</div>
```

But I have a couple of issues:
1- the blur doesn't last until I click okay to the alert and moves to the next page right away.
2- the alert is way up on the top of the page o can I some how move to the middle of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onclick="myFunction"
```

to

```
onclick=myFunction()
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('body').css("filter", "blur(2px)");
  alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="phone_num d-none d-xl-block">
  <a class="boxed-btn3" href="{% url 'homepage' %}" onclick=myFunction()>{% trans 'try' %}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't  fire the function insite the `html` tag. I would use a click event from JQuery. There you can place a `return false;` with prevents the browser from opening the link.

```js
$('.blurBtn').on('click', function(){
  $('body').css("filter","blur(2px)");
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phone_num d-none d-xl-block">
  <a class="boxed-btn3 blurBtn" href="{% url 'homepage' %}" onclick="myFunction">{% trans 'try' %}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser, where the alert message appears. Usually it's somewhere on the top of the screen. If you want an actual pop-up, I would recommend creating a custom one and the simply use the JQuery functions fadeIn() and fadeOut(). This way you can also customize the place of the pop-up.

```js
function myFunction() {
    $('body').css("filter","blur(2px)");
    alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phone_num d-none d-xl-block">
  <a class="boxed-btn3" href="#" onclick="myFunction()">blur bg</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but this may not match your need. Here's how to do it:

```
$('.blurBtn').on('click', function(){
  $('body').css("opacity","0.1");
  return false;
})
```